# Dynamic pagination with bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a code block that slices excess table rows. I can see those excess rows using the pagination that I created. My question is, How do I repeat this code block for 3 different organizations. Let's say I have org1, org2, and org3.

```
var rowsShown;
    $('#org1).after('<center><ul class="pagination" id="nav"></div><center>');
    rowsShown = 8;
    var rowsTotal = $('#data tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = rowsTotal/rowsShown;
    for(i = 0;i < numPages;i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#nav').append('<li><a href="#" rel="'+i+'" class="page">'+pageNum+'</a></li> ');
    }
    $('#org1 tbody tr').hide();
    $('#org1 tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#nav a:first').addClass('active');
    $('#nav a').bind('click', function(){

        $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $('#org1 tbody tr').css('opacity','0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
                css('display','table-row').animate({opacity:1}, 300);
    });
```

What my code does is it only displays and functions in one user/organization. I can just copy and paste this with different ids for org and nav, however, I am really aiming to avoid this kind of redundancy.

Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to change the #data to #org1 which is the id of the table

Comment: You can actually edit your post :)